# Gauss-Newton method -- is this matrix product invertible?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

In the Gauss-Newton method for solving overdetermined systems of equations,  the iteration matrix is of the form $(J^t   J)^{-1}   J^t$, for a $m \times n$ Jacobian matrix $J$ with $m > n$.   I was under the impression that if J had full column rank, then the product $J^t   J$ would always be invertible.   Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

Since $$\langle J^t Jx, x\rangle = \langle   Jx, Jx\rangle = \|Jx\|^2$$
it follows that $\ker J^tJ = \ker J$. In particular, if $\ker J=\{0\}$ ($J$ has full column rank), then $J^tJ$ is invertible.